# iOS - Changing window tint color changes font weight of done/save buttons

Tags: ios, tint

After changing the global tint color of my app using

```
window?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

in the **appDelegate**, the **Save** or **Done** buttons no longer respect the bold default font.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the UIBarButtonItem appearance to change the font

```
 //   let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 12) //customise with your font
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17);
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font], forState: UIControlState.Normal) ;
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah that worked but it also set the Cancel button to bold. I guess i could set each individual button's font. I was just hoping there was a global way of doing it. It's really strange that changing the color would affect the font weight.  The calendar app definitely has a normal Cancel and bold Add button, on the New Event popup. This almost seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had the button style set to Plain instead of Done. For Edit/Save/Done buttons you need to set the Style to Done and then set the Identifier to Edit/Save/Done etc.